# create column based on date/time of data

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have multiple sales data for the same day, I want to create a column for the revenue for the 1st sale and column for the revenue for the last sale. (first and last in time date order).

Below is my current and expected output:

```
   > df
       ID       Date Revenue
    1 113 23/04/2018      51
    2 113 24/04/2018      87
    3 113 25/04/2018      70
    4 112 23/04/2018      99
    5 112 24/04/2018      88
    6 110 23/04/2018      83



> data_desired
   ID       First.Revenue Last.Revenue
1 113             51           70
2 112             99           88
3 110             83           NA
```

Comment: Yes i will fix it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  arrange(ID, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(First.Revenue = first(Revenue), 
            Last.Revenue = last(Revenue), 
            Last.Revenue = ifelse(First.Revenue == Last.Revenue, NA, Last.Revenue))

#    ID First.Revenue Last.Revenue
#  <int>         <int>        <int>
#1   110            83           NA
#2   112            99           88
#3   113            51           70
```